# On Progress Event of SpriteSheet Animation Using createjs?

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I am using "onAnimationEnd" event but want to do some work when animation is progress. So I want to know current animated frame number via any progress or any event ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tick-event` (http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/BitmapAnimation.html#event_tick) and the use the properties `currentAnimation`, `currentAnimationFrame` and/or `currentFrame` (http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/BitmapAnimation.html#property_currentAnimation)

**Update:**
Sprite now dispatches a **[change event](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Sprite.html#event_change)** whenever the displayed frame changes.
(by [gskinner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2267275/gskinner) via comments)

Comment: As a note for anyone finding this answer in the future, `Sprite` now dispatches a `change` event whenever the displayed frame changes. http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Sprite.html#event_change